# Join over two relations in greenDao 2.1.0

Tags: android, join, greendao

I'm trying to select entity **A** while restricting them on a property in entity **C** by joining both through entity **B**:

> **A** {_id} <-- **B** {_id, A_id, C_id} --> **C** {_id, xy}

This is my code so far:

```
QueryBuilder<A> queryA = aDao.queryBuilder();
Join<A,B> joinAB = queryA.join(B.class, BDao.Properties.A_Id);

queryA.join(joinAB, BDao.Properties.C_id, C.class, CDao.Properties.Id)
            .where(CDao.Properties.xy.eq("stuff"))
```

In the last line the compiler expects a `Join<?,A>` instead of the `Join<A,B>` and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to chain the two joins for it to work.

If I start with a query over B I can just make the join to C and assign the restriction, but then I'd only load B and lazy-load A from there, which is not great, or deep-load B which also pulls in C, which is not great either.

From the documentation I got the impression that this kind of join-chaining is possible but I'm not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: Did you found solution? Same issue

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet, but also didn't look that hard and just used an SQL query for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you tried to achieve, what you did is right but you don't need to specify `<A,B>` while creating your join.
This should work :

```
QueryBuilder<A> queryA = aDao.queryBuilder();
Join joinAB = queryA.join(B.class, BDao.Properties.A_Id);
Join joinBC = queryA.join(joinAB, BDao.Properties.C_Id, C.class, CDAo.Properties.Id);
joinBC.where(CDao.Properties.xy.eq("stuff");
List<A> listA = queryA.list();
```

Comment: this just doent work. you should specify type parameters